# Sending data from Python to Javascript using EEL

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I am trying to send data from python to Javascript using EEL and their documentation and it does not seem to work... I keep getting null in my html / js page.

Here is what I have. Basically I want to get the link of the BING wallpaper and use it in my page as a background. But until then, I want to first get the result.

BING py script:

```
import bs4
import requests
import json


def scrape_bing():
   BASE_PATH = 'http://www.bing.com'
   BASE_REST = '/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US'
   URL = BASE_PATH + BASE_REST

   r = requests.get(url=URL)

   if r.status_code == 200:
      data = r.json()
      wallpaper_path = BASE_PATH + data['images'][0]['url']
      print(wallpaper_path)
   else:
      raise ValueError("[ERROR] non-200 response from Bing server for '{}'".format(URL))

   def main():
      scrape_bing()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

The script works and it returns my URL in the Python console.

My main.py which has EEL is as following:

```
import eel
from inc.bing import scrape_bing

eel.init('web')

myDef = scrape_bing()

@eel.expose
def bingR():
   return myDef

try:
   eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome', host='localhost', port=8274)

except (SystemExit, MemoryError, KeyboardInterrupt):
   pass

print ('Closed browser log...!')
```

I have used an async command just as in their examples, like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    async function run() {
        let n = await eel.bingR()();
        console.log('Got this from Python: ' + n);
    }

    run();

    </script>
```

Please help me understand how all this works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you accidentally formatted your code wrong, but it's a little off. Also you imported bs4 and json when you don't need to.

Your scrape_bing() function was not returning anything. It needs to return a value to  "**myDef**" when assigning it in "**myDef = scrape_bing()**".

I changed yours up a bit and came up with this example that will hopefully get you started. Hope this helps.

---

**main.py**

```
import eel
import requests

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose
def bingR():
    BASE_PATH = 'http://www.bing.com'
    BASE_REST = '/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US'
    URL = BASE_PATH + BASE_REST
    r = requests.get(url=URL)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        data = r.json()
        wallpaper_path = BASE_PATH + data['images'][0]['url']
        print(wallpaper_path)
        return wallpaper_path
    return 'No wallpaper found'

try:
    eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome', host='localhost', port=8274)
except (SystemExit, MemoryError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    pass

print ('Closed browser log...!')
```

**web\myscript.js**

```
async function run() {
    let n = await eel.bingR()();
    console.log('Got this from Python: ' + n);
    document.getElementById('output').value = n;
}
run();
```

**web\index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.js"></script>
  <input id="output" value="Output here" style="width: 700px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Also thanks for introducing me to eel. First time using it and really like it :)

Comment: Thank you ScamCast, everything is working like a charm. I wanted to add the bing code to a separate file and then append it into the main screen and I guess I messed things up. I want to create a desktop app and EEL seemed the way to go, as it allows you to use HTML + CSS :)