# is there a way to use eel functions in <div> attribute?

Tags: python, eel

So I am trying to make a clock using python and the eel library. I know i can easily make a clock using only JS and HTML, Im learning the eel library.
I tried implementing a simple clock with python returning the value back to the html and html calling the funcion every 1 second. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have read this StackOverflow post:
[Sending data from Python to Javascript using EEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596972/sending-data-from-python-to-javascript-using-eel)
and I followed all of the instructions.

Code:

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
      body {
    background: black;
    color: #02feff;
  }
  textarea.a{
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){thetime(); }, 1000);
</script>
<div id="output">Time: </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```py
import eel
import requests
from datetime import datetime
eel.init('stacktest1/web')

@eel.expose
def thetime():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time =", current_time)
    return current_time

try:
    eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome', host='localhost', port=8274)
except (SystemExit, MemoryError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    pass
print ('Closed browser log...!')
```

javascript

```js
function callback(current_time){
    document.getElementById("output").value=current_time
};
function thetime(){
eel.thetime()(callback)
}
```

Now, using  works, but i needed to replace  as 
when I do so, the app doesn't show any error, nor shows any output of Time
please spam ping me if you know
thanks

Comment: well, most of them

Answer (score 1):

The div to be updated referenced by `document.getElementById("output")` doesn't have a `value` property, rather `innerText` or `innerHTML`. If you change this everything else seems to work properly.

```py
document.getElementById("output").innerText=current_time
```